# Examples of existence proof by comparison of cardinalities

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, big-list

There is a famous [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/493952) of the existence of a transcendental number by comparison of cardinalities.

I would like to know more examples of existence proof by comparison of cardinalities.

Comment: See my answers to [Does the set of entire functions have the same cardinality as the reals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4192795/13130) *AND* [Do any proofs/properties rely on the distinction between some uncountable size and a larger uncountable size, in order for the proof/property to hold?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3671777/13130) There are probably a lot more examples in MSE by others.

Comment: See also: [Looking for a problem where one could use a cardinality argument to find a solution.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/350964) and [What are interesting examples of existential proofs based on cardinality arguments?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/747886)